# .save() function doesn't save all info

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a discord bot and what I want to do is when user write blacklisted word his `warn` data in collection will be incremented. But what I have now doesn't even save the warnings into the right collections and it doesn't save the `warns` data.

My data.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
var scheme = mongoose.Schema

const newScheme = new scheme({ userID2: String, warns: Number }, { collection: 'warnings' });
module.exports = mongoose.model('Warning', newScheme)
```

My index.js

```js
const Warning = require("./models/data.js");

if (foundInText) {
     Warning.findOne({
         userID2: message.author.id,
     }, (err, data) => {
         if (err) throw err
         if (!data) {
             const warningData = new Warning({
                 userID: message.author.id,
                 warns: 1
             })
               warningData.save().catch(err => console.log(err));
         } else {
                data.warns += 1;
                data.save().catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: based on your schema `const newScheme = new scheme({ userID2: String, warns: Number }, { collection: 'warnings' }`, i think you've typo on it?

Comment: Already fixed it but what typo do you mean ? Do you mean the `userID2` ?

Comment: Yes, is it fix already?

Comment: Yeah, check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a new file with that `warn` scheme and it worked. I don't know why but it does. It even creates a new collection.

The code in new file

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const newScheme = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    warns: Number,
    reason: Array,
    userID: String
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Warning', newScheme)
```

And then I've just updated the path and the name of the Warning

```js
const Warning = require('../../models/warns.js')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try by replacing `data` by `warns` because in your `data.js` you have nothing called `data`
Try with this :

```
const Warning = require("./models/data.js");

if (foundInText) {
     Warning.findOne({
         userID2: message.author.id,
     }, (err, warns) => {
         if (err) throw err
         if (!warns) {
             const warningData = new Warning({
                 userID: message.author.id,
                 warns: 1
             })
               warningData.save().catch(err => console.log(err));
         } else {
                warns.warns += 1;
                warns.save().catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Still doesn't save their `warns` into database